# Convert web page to Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, html, documents

It is known that web pages can be downloaded as [MHT](https://www.tagspaces.org/blog/mhtml-saving-chrome/) or [HTML](https://www.converter365.com/blog/how-to-convert-html-to-docx/#:%7E:text=tables%2C%20links%2C%20etc.-,How%20to%20save%20a%20webpage%20as%20HTML%20using%20Microsoft%20Edge,-%3F) files, and then opened in Word.

However, particularly with complex web pages, formatting can be lost, and only the text without much formatting or images is displayed in Word.

Online converters such as [Convertio](https://convertio.co/de/html-docx/) and [Cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/html-converter) do not work either, but give the same results without proper formatting and images as mentioned above.

I also tried several dedicated HTML editors, and they have the exact same problems as Word when opening arbitrary web pages, for example the below sample page. Almost all formatting is lost.

Is there another way to convert arbitrary web pages into Word documents?

[Example page](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/en/web/products-eurostat-news/w/ddn-20230721-1)

PS: Whoever downvoted this question for whatever reason that might have existed previously, consider removing that downvote.

Comment: Would a screen-grab be acceptable?

Comment: no, the editable web page is required, as a Word document

Comment: Have you tried printing the page to PDF? Word sometimes does a good job of opening PDFs in an editable form.

Comment: No, the original web page including all formatting, tables, images etc. is required as a Word document in Web View mode.

Comment: Those menus are going to be a problem in Word, for a start. Does it *have* to be Word, which you have already found is not really suitable, or would using a WYSIWYG HTML editor be possible?

Comment: a WYSIWYG HTML editor should be fine. From there, it should be possible to transfer the stuff over to Word in some way or the other.

Comment: I tried several WYSIWYG HTML editors, and they have the exact same problems as Word when opening arbitrary web pages, for example https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/en/web/products-eurostat-news/w/ddn-20230721-1. Almost all formatting is lost!

Answer (score 1):

1. There are online services for this, e.g., [Convertio](https://convertio.co/html-docx/) and [cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/html-to-docx).
2. MS Edge can [save a URL as DOCX](https://www.converter365.com/blog/how-to-convert-html-to-docx/).
3. There are also online [HTML to ODT converters](https://anyconv.com/html-to-odt-converter/).
4. Conversion can also be [done in LibreOffice](https://diegolamonica.info/how-to-convert-html-page-to-odt-or-doc-document/).

However, **DOCX ≠ HTML**. There are many features in HTML that will be lost when converting to any static document format. Consider a dynamically generated page such as [Sketchpad](https://sketch.io/sketchpad/) or [Kaleidoscope Painter](https://permadi.com/java/spaint/spaint.html) or [Random Number Generator](https://www.calculator.net/random-number-generator.html). You can get a snapshot, but not capture the page as such.

Comment: None of these work any better than already stated in the OP: "However, particularly with complex web pages, formatting can be lost, and only the text without any formatting or images is displayed in Word." Particularly, Edge can NOT "save a URL as DOCX", only as HTML or MHT, as stated in the OP.

Comment: Of course formatting will be lost as HTML and Word documents are very different and some of the features aren't even too portable if a tool wanted to cover everything in 100%, not sure what you're expecting. The question is also much more suitable here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered

Comment: HTML and Word documents are not that different, as normally Word can display every (at least static) HTML document near-perfectly in Web View mode. The problem here usually to be that Word doesn't find all needed CSS definitions. Same with dedicated HTML editors by the way.